# Java REST API stopped display java List

Tags: java, rest

I wrote simple rest api which has to display java list of objects. So I put two object of books into my database using JPARepository (which I implement in my BookService class) and now im trying to display that information. The problem is that when Im opening localhost page it displays only correct quantity of objects by {}, but when I use same method to display it in console it works correctly.

Example of localhost page:

```
[{},{}]
```

---

my code:

```java
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "author", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "publisher", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String publisher;

    public Book(int id, String title, String author, String publisher) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public Book() {}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", publisher='" + publisher + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

My rest controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("library/books")
public class BookController {
    private final BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    // localhost:8004/library/books
    @GetMapping()
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return bookService.index();
    }
}
```

---

```
    @Override
    public List<Book> index() {
    return bookRepository.findAll();
}
```

---

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simple-library</name>
    <description>simple-library</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.24</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```html
GET http://localhost:8007/library/books/

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 26 Dec 2021 15:44:11 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

[
  {},
  {}
]

Response code: 200; Time: 329ms; Content length: 7 bytes
```

Comment: What means "stopped"? What means "same method in console"?  Please show: method(`index()`), "in console", where/how you insert/what is the (some sample) data, which browser/curl/postman address, error logs(if any)!

Comment: @xerx593 , edited: method index() use findAll() method from JPARepository, stopped means that in previous project work correctly, in console - index().forEach(System.out::println)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now understand the problem:

You have (positive) `System.out` -put, but empty JSON response! (correct!?)

You "forgot" getters and setters, since that is how the (default) json mapping works!

Alternatively:

```
@JsonProperty
```

on the fields! ;)

For deeper studies ("drill" into):

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.json
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-message-conversion

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **lombok** dependency to **pom.xml** and and **@Data** annotation to your entity.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

**After that covert your entity with @Data annotation like below:**

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "author", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "publisher", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String publisher;
}
```